# WCF client receiving null response value

Tags: c#, wcf, null, response, producer-consumer

I have a simply wcf consumer client which sends "echo" requests to a 3rd party Java based producer.
I have struggled for some time to get the WS-Security functioning correctly but can now send requests and receive replies.
Only when the reply reaches my client, the value is null.

I have used IClientMessageInspector to verify I have the correct reply, but my call to the service always returns null.

Here is my client code; (The call to "MyEndPointBehavior" simply adds the message inspector)

```
string echoString = EchoTesttextbox.Text;

string url = "https://somewhere.com/uk-producer/UKService";

// create the endpoint address
EndpointAddress endPointAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(url), EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("TestProducer"));

PortBindingClient client = new PortBindingClient("Port12", endPointAddress);
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.Root, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, ".....");
client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.TrustedPeople, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, ".....");
client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new MyEndpointBehavior());

string response = String.Empty;
response = client.echo(echoString);

MessageBox.Show(response);
```

And my message inpector code;

```
public void AfterReceiveReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
{
     // Implement this method to inspect/modify messages after a message
     // is received but prior to passing it back to the client

     // make a copy of the reply that we can play with
     MessageBuffer buffer = reply.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
     // the message variable holds a reference to a copy of the initial reply
     Message message = buffer.CreateMessage();

     // assign a copy back to the ref received so it can continue undisturbed
     reply = buffer.CreateMessage();

     StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
     XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
     message.WriteBody(xmlTextWriter);
     xmlTextWriter.Flush();
     xmlTextWriter.Close();

     string body = stringWriter.ToString();

}
```

My question is what is happening between IClientMessageInspector.AfterReceiveReply and trying to show the response in my MessageBox?
If I can try and understand what is happening I can maybe try and work out why the reponse isn't passing through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well that was very frustrating.
The reason I was receiving a null value was all to do with the namespace.

Within IClientMessageInspector I could examine the SOAP body and see this

```
<soapenv:Body wsu:Id="Id-1555290177" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<me:EchoResponse xmlns:me="http://somewhere.com/uk-producer/UKService">test11</me:EchoResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
```

The WSDL and reference.cs (I've generated my proxy using the "Add Service Reference" feature of VS2012 from the 3rd party WSDL) show this;

```
[System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name="EchoResponse", Namespace="http://somewhere.com/uk-producer/UKService/", Order=0)]
public string EchoResponse1;
```

And for a long time that all looked ok.
But then, out of frustration I tried altering the reference.cs to this

```
[System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name="EchoResponse", Namespace="http://somewhere.com/uk-producer/UKService", Order=0)]
public string EchoResponse1;
```

> I only removed the last forward slash of the namespace

And it all worked.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your resolution David. I was encountering some null property values in the proxy class of my response from a service too. Through the use of SoapUI, I was able to validate the response I was getting and discovered, that whilst the namespace was correct, there was a mismatch in the namespace schema and the response schema.

We're using BTDF for our deployments and the issue was caused by the App_Data folder not being updated in IIS after making a change to the schemas.

Comment: For more details, on how to figure out the correct namespace which is required visit http:stackoverflow.com/a/31469374/1696326

Answer (score 1):

First set up a service (Even a stub) that does not use any security. Then look at the message it sends and compare to the message your inspector sends.

Comment: Ok I've done that - I don't understand why but gave it a go anyway. There are obvious differences, mainly due to the security elements in the Soap header.

Comment: in general it is ok for your inspector to strip out any security so the messages will be the same. Null usually comes out when there is a difference in the namespaces or root element names.

Answer (score 1):

This works. Remove body style attribute and try again.

The below attributes pass null value to the parameters

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, **BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest**,
         UriTemplate = "/GetactivityDetailsByActivityId")]
```

The below worked fine

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         UriTemplate = "/GetactivityDetailsByActivityId")]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get null response in WCF client, some advices:

- try to call the service in SoapUi with Validation of request and response turned on. It may be useful in detecting problems.
- debug Reference.cs file to see more closely what is going on
- use MessageInspector to see what is received in AfterReceiveReply method
- examine namespaces attentively, response often cannot be deserialized because of the difference in namespaces that are in Reference.cs and in real service

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me was to, in the Reference.cs file, update all of the MessageBodyMemberAttribute items where Namespace="" and to remove that.  For example, I started with:

```
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="", Order=0)]
    public MyService.userAuth authKey;
```

and changed it to:

```
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Order=0)]
    public MyService.userAuth authKey;
```

After this update I started to receive a response back from the SOAP service.